# Overflow columns

Tags: html, css

I have a theme that forces everything into a three column layout, which works most of the time. I have some content in a Toggle, and adding `overflow: auto;` to the Toggle definition in CSS allows any content that runs long on the right to work fine.
But I also have some stuff wrapped in a Code tag that would benefit from either running past the technical right edge of the column, but `overflow: auto;` does nothing when I add it to the Code style. Is this a limitation of Code, or Columns, or is there some way to do this I just haven't grokked yet?

@Chris W
I thought it might be something like that. But I added

```
div.px_overflow {
  overflow: auto!important;
}
```

to my CSS, and wrapped my Code nodes in `<div class="px_overflow"></div>`, but no change in behavior.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates the issue you are having

Comment: `<code>` is a phrase tag, just wrap it in a container element of your choosing and apply your css to that.